# Get product flavor or build variant in an android app

Tags: android, gradle

I have an android app with a number of different product flavors configured in my build.gradle file eg

```
productFlavors {
    someFlavor {}
    anotherFlavor {}
}
```

In my application code, I want to be able to get hold of the name of the currently compiled flavor (or build variant). One solution is this:

```
productFlavors {
    someFlavor {
        buildConfig "public static final String PRODUCT_FLAVOR = \"someFlavor\";"
    }
    anotherFlavor {
        buildConfig "public static final String PRODUCT_FLAVOR = \"anotherFlavor\";"
    }
}
```

And then in my android app call `BuildConfig.PRODUCT_FLAVOR`.

Is there some way I can get gradle to do this automatically? Or is there some other API in android I can use to get the product flavor name?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Edit: This is now done automatically starting with version 0.7 of the plugin. `BuildConfig.java` will contains

```
public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
public static final String FLAVOR = "f1Fa";
public static final String FLAVOR_group1 = "f1";
public static final String FLAVOR_group2 = "fa";
```

`FLAVOR` is the combined flavor name with all flavor dimensions/groups applied. Then each dimension is available as `FLAVOR_<group name>`.

Finally `BUILD_TYPE` contains the name of the used build type.

If you have a single flavor dimension, then you only have the `FLAVOR` constant.

<s>This is the only way to do it right now.</s>

One thing you could do is automate it. So you could do something like this:

```
android {
   productFlavors.whenObjectAdded { flavor ->
       flavor.buildConfig "public static final String PRODUCT_FLAVOR = \"${flavor.name}\";"
   }

   // your normal config here.
}
```

This way you don't have to manually do it for each flavor.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted - thanks. I found I needed to use whenObjectAdded instead of whenAdded, so I edited your answer, but basically this is correct.

Comment: Thanks very much for updating your answer - useful!

Comment: I want to get the selected build variant in build.gradle but whenObjectAdded is not working for me.
Here is what i am doing :
android {    
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {}
  flavor2 {}
    }
    productFlavors.whenObjectAdded { flavor ->
        println 'when object added : ' + flavor
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {}
        release {}
    }
}

Comment: I would like to make a paid apk from my package. But my Flavors box is empty, any idea?

Comment: Why is half this answer crossed out without any explanation or updated code?

Answer (score 7):

The accepted solution is awesome. For some cases, an alternate may be useful though.

You can add a config file, say 'Appconfig.java' to your productFlavor specific source folders i.e. `src/<productflavor>/java/<packagename>/Appconfig.java`; you can then use `Appconfig.PRODUCT_FLAVOR` in your app. The compiler will keep you honest and make sure you add this for all flavors.

Like I said, in this particular case, the accepted solution is probably better since you don't even need to add anything for new productFlavors but this approach might be useful for other cases.